# triggering any item in table

Tags: arrays, lua, fivem

writing a code to combine 2 items and i need help getting this to search the array for any of the items  to finish string basically im trying to get it to use
*this **or** this **or** this*

trying to get

> needItem

to use

> backwood

array

```
    ESX = nil
 
backwood = {'backwoods_grape', 'backwoods_honey', 'backwoods_russian_cream'}


TriggerEvent('esx:getSharedObject', function(obj) ESX = obj end)

ESX.RegisterUsableItem('whitewidow', function(source)
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)
    combineTwoItems(source, xPlayer, 'whitewidow', backwood, 1, 'jointwhitewidow', 1, "Blunt of White Widow", 10000, "mp_arresting", "a_uncuff")
end)


function check(backwood, value)
    for _,v in ipairs(backwood) do
        if v == value then
           function combineTwoItems()
        end
    end
end

function combineTwoItems(source, xPlayer, useItem, needItem, needItemCount, resultItem, resultItemCount, progressbarTitle, progressbarDuration, animationClass, animation)
    local itemCount = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(tostring(needItem)).count
    if itemCount >= needItemCount then
        TriggerClientEvent('ScriptCombineItems:playanimation', source, progressbarTitle, progressbarDuration, animationClass, animation)
        Citizen.Wait(progressbarDuration)
        xPlayer.removeInventoryItem(useItem, 1)
        xPlayer.removeInventoryItem(needItem, needItemCount)
        xPlayer.addInventoryItem(resultItem, resultItemCount) 
    else
        TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', source, 'You need '.. needItemCount.. 'x ~r~'.. needItem .. '~s~ !')
    end
end
```

Comment: `function combineTwoItems()` is a syntax error. Can you please define the error? What stops you from iterating over the items you need?

Comment: all i know s that when i run this it gets stuck when they are about to combine @Luke100000